# How to reset the hub command to ask username and password

Tags: git, git-fork

I am trying to fork the git repo using hub

```
hub fork --remote-name=origin
Error creating fork: Forbidden (HTTP 403)
Resource protected by organization SAML enforcement. You must grant your personal token access to this organization.
```

I would like to re-enter my username and password but I'm not sure if I know how to reset hub fork command.

Any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have [2FA](https://help.github.com/en/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) (two-factor authentication) activated for your account.

Because in that case, `hub` or not, you [would need a PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line) to access your repository when pushing.

Check what "`origin`" is for (`git remote -v`): if it is an HTTPS URL without the token in it, your credentials might be cached (git config credential.helper)

In both cases, `hub` is not directly involved, and would not need to be "ressetted".

Comment: I have a PAT , but to reenter the username/ PAT I want hub to prompt me again ( is the expectation right - not sure) but I am not able to use the command further.

Comment: @user269867 entering your username/PAT would mean GitHub would *not* prompt you again (since it knows it is you)

Comment: So what are some next steps?git remote -v is with no token in it and ```git config credential.helper``` return osxkeychain

Comment: @user269867 You can, for testing, modify your remote URL: git remote set-url origin https://<username>:<PAT>@github.com/<username>/yyy`

Comment: And check what github.com entry you have in your keychain (https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)